# Why there is no question mark after "said"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, punctuation

In *[The Old Guard (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Old_Guard_(2020_film))*, Nile joins immportal team:

> Nile: How are you all in my dreams?
>
> Genova: We dream of each other. They stop when we meet.  I believe
> it's because we... we're meant to find each other. It's like destiny.
>
> Livre: No, more like misery loves company.

(Nile looks towards Andy)

> Andy: **What he said**.

Why there is no question mark after "said"?

Comment: It's not a question - it essentially means "**I say** or **agree with** what he said."

Comment: “It's not a question - it essentially means "I say or agree with what he said."” - Ditto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to ELL Stack Exchange

Andy here isn't asking what was spoken, that would have been

> Andy: **What did he say?**

He's trying to **reinforce** Livre's / Genova's opinion

> Andy: **I agree with what he said.**